# How to disable showing a single chart in legend area?

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I have a line chart with multiple lines in it just like in an example: http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html.

Is it possible by passing parameters to the chart to hide a label for any chart in legend?

For example, hide `Sine Wave` label from legend but keep the chart line itself as it is.

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the classic legend, create your own html legend based on your data, and Use the nvd3 options > chart callback

```
    chart: any;

    this.options = {
       chart: {
       showLegend: false, ...
       callback: (chart) => {
         this.chart = chart;
    }
```

EDIT : to update your chart => this.chart.update() and add a "disabled" flag for each of your data rows like :

```
    data[0] = { "key": label,
    "color": color,
    "disabled": false,
    "values": { "label": labelValue, "value": val };
```